# find the kernel of the linear transformation on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

$L: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is defined by $L(A) = A + A^T$

I found the kernel of this linear transformation and it will consist of matrices of the following form:

$A$ such that $a_{ii} = 0$ for all $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$ and $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$ for all $i \neq j$.

But what is the basis for this and the dimension?

Comment: The kernel is the set of antisymmetric matrices.

Comment: You can consider matrices with zeros everywhere except for a $1$ at $i,j$ and a $-1$ at $j,i$, with $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest basis I can think of.

For each $i,j$ pair with $i>j, a_{ij} = 1$ and $a_{ji} = -1$  Place zeros elsewhere.

How many vectors can be define this way? It is the equal to the number of elements in the upper triangle excluding the main diagonal.

$\frac 12 (n)(n-1)$